# Icons for in-app products or subscriptions on Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm using the [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/package-summary) version 3 to fetch in-app and subscription products.

After calling `querySkuDetailsAsync` on the `BillingClient` object, I'm correctly getting the [SkuDetails](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails) for each product.

Besides the product title, description, price, and other info, there is a method called [getIconUrl()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails#getIconUrl()), which supposedly should return the icon of the product if present.

However, in the current Google Play Console, there is no way of adding icons for products. Or at least I did not find any.

**How can I add an icon to an in-app product or subscription?**

Comment: Interestingly, in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153481?hl=en#zippy=) they mention an "icon" that you can set on one-time-purchases. But even there it's wrong, the play console doesn't offer this anymore and the docs are outdated